# Why the dashboard of the SonarQube 4.3 does not display the languages?

Tags: dashboard, sonarqube

My company uses SonarQube to analyze code, and the new version 4.3 of the sonar does not show the languages ​​of each project in the dashboard. Could someone tell me the way to fix this problem?

I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: give us some specifics.  What did you try?  What is your screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [SonarQube 4.2](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Release+4.2+Upgrade+Notes), projects are analyzed using a multi-language strategy, so it does not really make sense anymore to display a project's (single) language, since one project can contain several analyzed file types (think e.g Java, XML, HTML, CSS and JavaScript for a Web application with a Java backend).

Note that in the upcoming SonarQube 4.4, the Project Size widget has been revamped to display distribution of lines of code by language.

Comment: Is it possible to create dashboards containing only projects of a choosen language?
Before we were able to create a "view" (the "views plugin" was used) for a selected language. We were able to show the content of this view on a dashboard later. But now we are not able to create such "language orientated views", correct?

Comment: You are right, the option to define views by language has been removed in the latest releases (since it has no real meaning anymore). As a workaround, you can define a manual metric to set the "main language" of a project, and define views based on this manual metric.